# Where should I ask a question about converting from Java to C++?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I understand that this would not be constructive to those looking for a specific answer. However, I would like to get some feedback about other's experiences going (back in my case) to C++ from Java or some other managed language.

Of course I would like to post it in the appropriate location. Is there such a location within SO/SE?

Comment: So rather than converting code (which you title seems to hint at), you want to ask about how a Java programmer can more easily pick up C++ (again)?

Comment: There are already [a few similar questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2B"c%2B%2B"+%2Bjava&submit=search) on programmers.

Comment: FYI, automated conversion from one programming language to another is called transcompiling.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any place in the SE network for such an open ended questions.

SE focuses on specific questions that can be answered, and a question like that sounds more like a poll asking users for shared experiences, or something that promotes discussion.

Your best bet would be to ask in one of the [SE chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). There are rooms for specific languages, so try asking in the C++ or the Java chat room.

I'm fairly sure a question like this would get closed pretty quickly on Programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Rachel is right, it is a bit of a stretch to say this question is a good fit for the Stack Exchange system at all in its current state. First, refine your question a bit, look for something that is specific and answerable, and then, and only then, I would ask that question on Programmers. Stack Overflow is about specific programming problems, while yours less about *code* and more about *coding*, a better fit for Programmers.

[This question is a good guide for what you should end up with.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74731/c-for-java-programmers) See how it differs from your in that it asks

> I want to point out the most important "gotchas" and C++ features when migrating from Java to C++.

rather than your question

> I would like to get some feedback about other's experiences going to C++ from Java

See the difference?  <sub>Hint: the word "feedback" is killing you.</sub>

Comment: There's a reason why this question has lasted 12 hours with no-one saying that... everyone's afraid of Yannis :-)

Comment: The whole time I was typing this, I was scared somebody would jump out of my monitor and scream at me for dumping questions unfit for SO onto Programmers...

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you, however I'm fairly sure such a question would get closed quickly on Programmers. They abide by the same SE question guidelines, although their focus is on conceptual software development instead of actual code.

Comment: You're right. I edited to fix that. Recommending somebody ask on Programmers is always such dangerous territory.